# Is it possible to chain multiple partitionBy?

Tags: java

I have a record Person as below:

```
public record Person(boolean male, int age) {}
```

And I want to split a `List` of `Person` into 4 different lists: males over 18, males under 18 and the same for females, what I have so far is:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Person>> peopleDividedBySex = people.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Person::male));
List<Person> males = peopleDividedBySex.get(Boolean.TRUE);
List<Person> females = peopleDividedBySex.get(Boolean.FALSE);
Map<Boolean, List<Person>> malesDividedByAge = males.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(person -> person.age() > 18));
List<Person> malesOverEighteen = malesDividedByAge.get(Boolean.TRUE);
List<Person> malesUnderEighteen = malesDividedByAge.get(Boolean.FALSE);
Map<Boolean, List<Person>> femalesDividedByAge = males.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(person -> person.age() > 18));
List<Person> femalesOverEighteen = femalesDividedByAge.get(Boolean.TRUE);
List<Person> femalesUnderEighteen = femalesDividedByAge.get(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Is it possible to do it in one chainable `partitioningBy` method in order to avoid creating the other streams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can partition with another downstream partition collector:

```
Map<Boolean, Map<Boolean, List<Person>>> partitioned = persons.stream()
        .collect(partitioningBy(Person::male, partitioningBy(p -> p.age() < 18)));

List<Person> malesUnder18 = partitioned.get(true).get(true);
List<Person> malesOver18 = partitioned.get(true).get(false);
List<Person> femalesUnder18 = partitioned.get(false).get(true);
List<Person> femalesOver18 = partitioned.get(false).get(false);
```

Comment: I have another use case that I have to split males over 18, males under 18 and females regardless of their ages, is it possible?

Comment: You could combine the female lists, of course. Or you can use a custom enum key: `groupingBy(p -> !p.male() ? FEMALE : p.age() < 18 ? UNDER : OVER)`

Comment: Could you edit your answer with the enum option you gave?

Comment: I tried `people.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> !p.male() ? Teste.FEMALE : p.age() < 18 ? Teste.UNDER : Teste.OVER))` but it's giving me a compilation error with the message `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Teste to boolean`.

Comment: I said `Collectors.groupingBy()`

Comment: You might want to post a new question.

Comment: My mistake, `groupingBy` worked like a charm.